# How to implement a pseudo blocking async queue in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

So here's an oxymoron: I want to create an asynchronous blocking queue in javascript/typescript (if you can implement it without typescript, that's fine). Basically I want to implement something like Java's `BlockingQueue` expect instead of it actually being blocking, it would be async and I can await dequeues.

Here's the interface I want to implement:

```
interface AsyncBlockingQueue<T> {
  enqueue(t: T): void;
  dequeue(): Promise<T>;
}
```

And I'd use it like so:

```
// enqueue stuff somewhere else

async function useBlockingQueue() {
  // as soon as something is enqueued, the promise will be resolved:
  const value = await asyncBlockingQueue.dequeue();
  // this will cause it to await for a second value
  const secondValue = await asyncBlockingQueue.dequeue();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, `dequeue` will create a promise that `enqueue` will resolve. We just have to keep the resolvers in a queue - and also care about the case where values are enqueued before they are dequeued, keeping the already fulfilled promises in a queue.

```
class AsyncBlockingQueue {
  constructor() {
    // invariant: at least one of the arrays is empty
    this.resolvers = [];
    this.promises = [];
  }
  _add() {
    this.promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
      this.resolvers.push(resolve);
    }));
  }
  enqueue(t) {
    // if (this.resolvers.length) this.resolvers.shift()(t);
    // else this.promises.push(Promise.resolve(t));
    if (!this.resolvers.length) this._add();
    this.resolvers.shift()(t);
  }
  dequeue() {
    if (!this.promises.length) this._add();
    return this.promises.shift();
  }
  // now some utilities:
  isEmpty() { // there are no values available
    return !this.promises.length; // this.length <= 0
  }
  isBlocked() { // it's waiting for values
    return !!this.resolvers.length; // this.length < 0
  }
  get length() {
    return this.promises.length - this.resolvers.length;
  }
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    // Todo: Use AsyncIterator.from()
    return {
      next: () => this.dequeue().then(value => ({done: false, value})),
      [Symbol.asyncIterator]() { return this; },
    };
  }
}
```

I don't know TypeScript, but presumably it's simple to add the the necessary type annotations.

For better performance, use a Queue implementation with circular buffers instead of plain arrays, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/petkaantonov/deque). You might also use only a single queue and remember whether you currently store promises or resolvers.

Comment: I'd like to thank stackoverflow for making me add more `!` to reach the character minimum

Comment: @Bergi In this solution, why is there the check `if (!this.resolvers.length)` in `enqueue`? The logic appears to encode the creation of a Promise (and a resolver), and then the immediate removal of the resolver. What am I missing? Does the length of the array of resolvers ever get above 1?

Comment: @52d6c6af The length of the resolvers goes above 0 when there were more `dequeue()` calls than `enqueue()` calls, the length of the promises goes above 0 when there were more `enqueue()` calls than `dequeue()` calls.

Comment: @52d6c6af No, I don't think this has to do anything with [the trampolines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) that I know

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I've added a `requeue` function that adds a Promise at the head of the array. This way I can do a `NO-ACK` and still maintain the sequence of enqueued items:

`
requeue(t) {
    if (!this.promises.length) {
      this._add()
    } else {
      this.promises.unshift(new Promise(resolve => {
        this.resolvingFunctions.unshift(resolve)
      }))
    }
    this.resolvingFunctions.shift()(t)
  }
`