# Asynchronous Bounded Queue in JS/TS using async/await

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my head around `async/await`, and I have the following code:

```
class AsyncQueue<T> {
    queue = Array<T>()
    maxSize = 1

    async enqueue(x: T) {
        if (this.queue.length > this.maxSize) {
            // Block until available
        }

        this.queue.unshift(x)
    }

    async dequeue() {
        if (this.queue.length == 0) {
            // Block until available
        }

        return this.queue.pop()!
    }
}

async function produce<T>(q: AsyncQueue, x: T) {
    await q.enqueue(x)
}

async function consume<T>(q: AsyncQueue): T {
    return await q.dequeue()
}

// Expecting 3 4 in the console
(async () => {
    const q = new AsyncQueue<number>()
    consume(q).then(console.log)
    consume(q).then(console.log)
    produce(q, 3)
    produce(q, 4)
    consume(q).then(console.log)
    consume(q).then(console.log)
})()
```

My problem, of course, is in the "Block until available" parts of the code. I was expecting to be able to "halt" the execution until something happens (for example, dequeue halts until an enqueue exists, and vice-versa given the available space). I have the feeling I might need to use coroutines for this, but I really wanted to make sure I am just not missing any `async/await` magic here.

Comment: You *don't* want to `block`, that would freeze the script - you should have `enqueue` and `dequeue` `await` promises that resolve once whatever they're waiting on is available. Also, you should call constructors with `()`

Comment: It seems I am pushing the `async/await` game further and further, and it isn't clear to me how it would all solve down.

Comment: Have a look at the possible duplicate [How to implement a pseudo blocking async queue in JS/TS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47157428/1048572)

Comment: No, you don't need coroutines, you just need the `new Promise` constructor to wait for things that happen externally. You are however *implementing* coroutines, [CSP-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**17/04/2019 Update:** Long story short, there's a bug in the AsyncSemaphore implementation below, that was caught using [property-based](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-check) testing. [You can read all about this "tale" here](http://hugosereno.eu/blog/2019/04/16/a-tale-of-async-and-tests/). Here's the fixed version:

```
class AsyncSemaphore {
    private promises = Array<() => void>()

    constructor(private permits: number) {}

    signal() {
        this.permits += 1
        if (this.promises.length > 0) this.promises.pop()!()
    }

    async wait() {
        this.permits -= 1
        if (this.permits < 0 || this.promises.length > 0)
            await new Promise(r => this.promises.unshift(r))
    }
}
```

---

Finally, after considerable effort, and inspired by @Titian answer, I think I solved this. The code is filled with debug messages, but it might serve *pedagogical* purposes regarding the flow of control:

```
class AsyncQueue<T> {
    waitingEnqueue = new Array<() => void>()
    waitingDequeue = new Array<() => void>()
    enqueuePointer = 0
    dequeuePointer = 0
    queue = Array<T>()
    maxSize = 1
    trace = 0

    async enqueue(x: T) {
        this.trace += 1
        const localTrace = this.trace

        if ((this.queue.length + 1) > this.maxSize || this.waitingDequeue.length > 0) {
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Producer Waiting`)
            this.dequeuePointer += 1
            await new Promise(r => this.waitingDequeue.unshift(r))
            this.waitingDequeue.pop()
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Producer Ready`)
        }

        this.queue.unshift(x)
        console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Enqueueing ${x} Queue is now [${this.queue.join(', ')}]`)

        if (this.enqueuePointer > 0) {
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Notify Consumer`)
            this.waitingEnqueue[this.enqueuePointer-1]()
            this.enqueuePointer -= 1
        }
    }

    async dequeue() {
        this.trace += 1
        const localTrace = this.trace

        console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Queue length before pop: ${this.queue.length}`)

        if (this.queue.length == 0 || this.waitingEnqueue.length > 0) {
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Consumer Waiting`)
            this.enqueuePointer += 1
            await new Promise(r => this.waitingEnqueue.unshift(r))
            this.waitingEnqueue.pop()
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Consumer Ready`)
        }

        const x = this.queue.pop()!
        console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Queue length after pop: ${this.queue.length} Popping ${x}`)

        if (this.dequeuePointer > 0) {
            console.debug(`[${localTrace}] Notify Producer`)
            this.waitingDequeue[this.dequeuePointer - 1]()
            this.dequeuePointer -= 1
        }

        return x
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Here's a clean version using an `AsyncSemaphore`, that really encapsulates the way things are usually done using concurrency primitives, but adapted to the asynchronous-CPS-single-threaded-event-loop™ style of JavaScript with `async/await`. You can see that the logic of `AsyncQueue` becomes much more intuitive, and the double synchronisation through Promises is delegated to the two [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)):

```
class AsyncSemaphore {
    private promises = Array<() => void>()

    constructor(private permits: number) {}

    signal() {
        this.permits += 1
        if (this.promises.length > 0) this.promises.pop()()
    }

    async wait() {
        if (this.permits == 0 || this.promises.length > 0)
            await new Promise(r => this.promises.unshift(r))
        this.permits -= 1
    }
}

class AsyncQueue<T> {
    private queue = Array<T>()
    private waitingEnqueue: AsyncSemaphore
    private waitingDequeue: AsyncSemaphore

    constructor(readonly maxSize: number) {
        this.waitingEnqueue = new AsyncSemaphore(0)
        this.waitingDequeue = new AsyncSemaphore(maxSize)
    }

    async enqueue(x: T) {
        await this.waitingDequeue.wait()
        this.queue.unshift(x)
        this.waitingEnqueue.signal()
    }

    async dequeue() {
        await this.waitingEnqueue.wait()
        this.waitingDequeue.signal()
        return this.queue.pop()!
    }
}
```

---

**Update 2:** There seemed to be a subtle bug hidden in the above code, that became evident when trying to use an `AsyncQueue` of size 0. The semantics do make sense: it is a queue without any buffer, where the publisher always awaits for an consumer to exist. The lines that were preventing it to work were:

```
await this.waitingEnqueue.wait()
this.waitingDequeue.signal()
```

If you look closely, you'll see that `dequeue()` isn't perfectly symmetric to `enqueue()`. In fact, if one swaps the order of these two instructions:

```
this.waitingDequeue.signal()
await this.waitingEnqueue.wait()
```

Then all works again; it seems intuitive to me that we signal that there's something interested in `dequeuing()` before actually waiting for an `enqueuing` to take place.

I'm still not sure this doesn't reintroduce subtle bugs, without extensive testing. I'll leave this as a challenge ;)

Comment: Glad to see you got some use out of the answer. I got caught up with other things and didn't have time to debug it. I deleted the original answer as it was getting down votes, deservedly so.