# Websocket waiting for server response with a queue

Tags: javascript, websocket, promise, async-await

I'm using websocket to send and receive data (up to 30 small messages per seconds). I want the client to send a websocket payload and wait for a specific message from the server.

Flow:

The client send a request

It also store the requestId (163) in `waitingResponse` object as a new object with `sent` timestamp

```
waitingResponse = {
  163: { sent: 1583253453549 }
}
```

When the server response, another function validate the payload and then append the result to that request object

```
waitingResponse = {
  163: { sent: 1583253453549, action: "none" }
}
```

The client checks every x ms that object for the `action` key

I have a function `sendPayload` that sends the payload and then await for a value from `awaitResponse` (the function below). Right now this function doesn't work. I tried making 2 separate function, one that would be the setTimeout timer, the other was the promise. I also tried having both in the same function and decide if it was the loop or the promise with the `original` argument you can see below. Now I'm thinking that function should always return a promise even in the loop but I cannot seem to make that work with a timer and I'm afraid of the cost of multiple promise in one another. Let's say I check for a response every 5 ms and the timeout it 2000ms. That is a lot of promises.

```
public async sendPayload(details) {
    console.log("sendPlayload", details);

    this.waitingResponse[details.requestId] = { sent: +new Date() };

    if (this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(details));
    }
    const bindAwaitResponse = this.awaitResponse.bind(this);
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        const result = await bindAwaitResponse(details.requestId, true);
        console.log("RES", result);
        console.info("Time took", (+new Date() - result.sent) / 1000);

        resolve(result);
    });

}

public async awaitResponse(requestId, original) {
    // console.log(requestId, "awaitResponse")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Is it a valid queued request
        if (this.waitingResponse[requestId]) {
            // Do we have an answer?
            if (this.waitingResponse[requestId].hasOwnProperty("action")) {
                console.log(requestId, "Got a response");
                const tmp = this.waitingResponse[requestId];
                delete this.waitingResponse[requestId]; // Cleanup
                resolve(tmp);
            } else {
                // No answer yet from remote server
                // console.log("no answer: ", JSON.stringify(this.waitingResponse));
                // Check if request took too long
                if (+new Date() - this.waitingResponse[requestId].sent > 5000) { // TODO: Option for time out
                    console.warn(requestId, "Request timed out");

                    // Timed out, result took too long
                    // TODO: Option, default action when timed out
                    delete this.waitingResponse[requestId];  // Cleanup
                    resolve({
                        action: "to" // For now, just sent a timeout action, maybe the default action should be outside of the Network class?
                    })
                } else {
                    // console.log(requestId, "Still waiting for results");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.waitingResponse));
                    // Still waiting, after x ms, recall function
                    return setTimeout(async () => { resolve(await this.awaitResponse(requestId, false)); }, 200);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private async processMessage(msg) {
    console.log("WS received Message", JSON.stringify(msg.data));

    console.log("Current: ", JSON.stringify(this.waitingResponse));

    let data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    // console.log("Received: ", data);


    if (data.hasOwnProperty("requestId") && this.waitingResponse[data.requestId]) {
        // console.log("processMessage ID found");
        this.waitingResponse[data.requestId] = { ...data, ...this.waitingResponse[data.requestId] };

    }
}
```

Note: I put the `websocket` tag below because I looked hard for that. Maybe I came across the solution without even realising it, but if you have better tags for this question to be found easier, please edit them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you're mixing a lot of callback style functions with intermediate promises and `async`/`await`. Don't do polling when waiting for a response! Instead, when [writing a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157577/1048572), put the `resolve` function itself in the queue so that you can directly fulfill/reject the respective promise from the response handler.

In your case:

```
public async sendPayload(details) {
    const request = this.waitingResponse[details.requestId] = { sent: +new Date() };
    try {
        if (this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
           this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(details));
        }
        const result = await new Promise(function(resolve) {
            request.resolve = resolve;

            setTimeout(() => {
                reject(new Error('Timeout')); // or resolve({action: "to"}), or whatever
            }, 5000);
        });
        console.info("Time took", (+new Date() - request.sent) / 1000);
        return result; // or {...request, ...result} if you care
    } finally {
        delete this.waitingResponse[details.requestId];
    }
}


private async processMessage(msg) {
    let data = JSON.parse(msg.data);

    if (data.hasOwnProperty("requestId") {
        const request = this.waitingResponse[data.requestId]
        if (request)
            request.resolve(data)
        else
            console.warn("Got data but found no associated request, already timed out?", data)
    } else {
        console.warn("Got data without request id", data);
    }
}
```

You might even do away with the `request` object altogether and only store the `resolve` function itself, if the `processMessage` function does not need any details about the request.

Comment: You are a magician! I never thought about putting the `resolve` function in the object and call it later. That code is awesome.

Comment: Simply spectacular! The best and most elegant answer I saw in Stack Overflow ever! Thank you