# Is it possible to wrap a setInterval in an async generator function?

Tags: javascript

Without using the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API), is it possible to wrap a `setInterval` in an async generator function, to simulate a never-ending stream?

I know how to do it using `setTimeout` to supply the delay.

Using `setTimeout`:

```js
const wait = (delay = 500) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))

async function * countUp(count = 0) {           
    while(1) (await wait(), yield count++)           
}

(async ()=> {
    for await(let el of countUp())
        console.log(el)
})()
```

Comment: You could, but I don't think it would be as tidy as using setTimeout  as a promise delay.

Comment: @52d6c6af fair enough, i guess your question is an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Or: not easily. Async generator functions are promise based, and promises don't deal well with repetitive callbacks. Also `setInterval` does not support any form of backpressure.

Of course you can implement the streams API yourself, which comes down to making [a queue of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157577/1048572). You can take the code from that answer and write

```
function countUp(count = 0) {
    const q = new AsyncBlockingQueue()
    setInterval(() => {
        q.enqueue(count++)
    }, 500)
    return q // has a Symbol.asyncIterator method
}

(async() => {
    for await (const el of countUp())
        console.log(el)
})()
```

Comment: So the answer is actually "yes", but it is much more difficult?

Comment: Not just more difficult, but also more inefficient and possibly incorrect if the consumer doesn't keep up with the rate of production