# Wait for an async operation inside asyncIterator generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

I have this `Queue` class (not the real implementation, but it exemplifies my point):

```
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this._arr = [];
    }

    async push(elem) {
        this._arr.push(elem);
    }

    async pop() {
        return this._arr.pop();
    }

    *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        do {
            let res = await this.pop(); // here is the problem
            if (res) yield res;
        } while (res);
    }
}
```

It's just a wrapper for  a Javascript `Array` with the exception that its methods return a `Promise`.

What I want to do is to yield conditionally based on the return value of the `pop()` method, which I cannot do because `await` is not a valid operation inside an `asyncIterator` generator function.

I thought about having a flag which is set in the previous iteration:

```
*[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let continue = true;
    do {
        yield this.pop().then(v => {
            if (!v) continue = false;
            return v
        });
    } while (continue);
}
```

But this would still return a `undefined` value in the last execution of `pop()`.

I could handle this in the calling code by checking for a `undefined` value as a signal of the end of the iteration, but I was wondering if there was a better approach at tackling this problem.

Comment: For a real queue implementation maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157577/1048572). It also implements `[Symbol.asyncIterator]()` fittingly, without any generator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`async` generator function](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#async-generator-functions) (MDN docs missing, but see e.g. [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/)) for the implementation of the [`[Symbol.asyncIterator]()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator):

```
async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() { /*
^^^^^ */
    while (this._arr.length) {
        yield await this.pop(); // no longer a problem
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the simplicity. I knew something like this existed somewhere. Thanks!