# need to make generator pause for a bit instead of immediately yielding

Tags: javascript, generator

So, my function looks like so

```
async function* doIt(arr){
    let counter = 0;
    while(true) yield arr[counter++];
}

(async() => {
    let arr = [1,2,3];
    let x = doIt(arr);
    setTimeout(() => {arr.push(4)}, 3000);
    await x.next();
    await x.next();
    await x.next();
    await x.next(); //I want to pause here until 4 has arrived, instead, got undefined
})()
```

I was hoping `await` here would cause `doIt` to pause after `3` until `4` has arrived. how can I achieve this? is this doable? I need the program not halted while waiting for `4`

Thanks

Comment: yes, I'm perfectly fine with not awaiting setTimeout, but I need `doIt` to pause until `4` arrive.

Comment: so, basically, I need `doIt` to await on `arr` I guess

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. `doIt` would basically need to poll the array to get another element. Instead, [use a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157577/1048572) and put the `4` in it after 3s, which can immediately notify the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the waiting action to be abstracted inside the generator, I think you'll need to connect the asynchronous `arr.push(4)` with the generator. As is, it's completely disconnected from it, so there's no good way inside `doIt` to determine when exactly the array will get populated (short of something gross like putting a setter on the array property and returning a Promise that resolves when the setter gets invoked). You will need to somehow restructure the code so that the `arr.push` callback can communicate to the generator that something has changed - the existing structure isn't suitable for it in the same way that an asynchronous action inside a [dangling Promise](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) can't be hooked into from the outside.

There are a few approaches that could be used, but one would be to pass promises to `doIt` as well. When a Promise resolves, that indicates that something in the array may have changed, and the generator can re-check the index.

```js
async function* doIt(arr, ...promises){
    let counter = 0;
    while(true) {
      if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(counter)) {
        await Promise.any(promises);
      }
      if (arr.hasOwnProperty(counter)) {
        yield arr[counter++];
      }
    }
}

(async() => {
    console.log('start');
    let arr = [1,2,3];
    let x = doIt(
      arr,
      new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(
          () => {arr.push(4); res()},
          3000
        )
      })
    );
    await x.next();
    await x.next();
    await x.next();
    console.log('got 3');
    await x.next(); //I want to pause here until 4 has arrived, instead, got undefined
    console.log('got 4');
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a promise and await that:

```js
const p = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    arr.push(4);
    resolve();
  }, 3000);
});

await x.next();
await x.next();
await x.next();

await p; // wait for 4

// do other stuff
```

Comment: amazing, this might just work, I'm still outside, let me try this when I get back to my pc. if this works, I'll accept this answer.